# Autolock Google Sheets cell after data is entered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to restrict a user edit a cell post updating data in it. Only the owner of the sheet should have access to update data in the cell in google sheets

eg: User1 has access to the sheet and can update data in a cell. Once user1 updates the data and come out of the cell, user1 and rest of the users who have access to the sheet shouldn't have access to edit the cell. I have the below code, but users who have updated the cell still have access to edit the data in it. Please help.

Here is the sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4z_7Tuy54e6T3bEoTVHwvsusrfG2t9dLX7KeO9oYX0/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(e){
const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
if (e.range.columnStart != 4) return;
let protection = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getMaxColumns()).protect();
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
}
```

Comment: Will that user need to go back and edit that protected cell later on?

Comment: No, I need to restrict the user to edit